# Should URLs be encoded with encodeURIComponent() or escape()?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I am trying to encode URL using `encodeURIComponent` method. Some parameters in URL also contain special characters (of ISO-8859-1 charset) like `é`, `è`, which are not correctly encoded.

For example `é`is encoded to `%C3%A9` instead of `%E9`

As a alternative I have used `escape` method for encoding and it is working absolutely fine.

But it does not encode some characters like `+ - * / . _ @`

I am in doubt whether i should use it or not and most of the articles say that `escape()` should be avoided. Can anyone please tell me how can I get the correct encoding using `encodeURIComponent` or should I use `escape`?

**CODE:** there is a function "get" in which request is sent and encodeFormularDatas is used to encode url parameters. HTML page encoding is ISO-8859-1.

```
this.get = function(url, answerTreatement, options) {
  var request = this.newRequest();
  var target = url;
  if (options.parameters) { 
     target += "?"+this.encodeFormularDatas(options.parameters);
  }

  request.open("POST", target, true);
  request.send(null);
}
this.encodeFormularDatas = function(values) {
   var pairs = [];
   var regexp = /%20/g; // encoded space

   for (var name in values) {
      var value = values[name];
      var pair = encodeURIComponent(name).replace(regexp, "+") + '=' + 
                 encodeURIComponent(value).replace(regexp, "+");        
      pairs.push(pair);
   }
   return pairs.join('&');
};
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: Stick with `encodeURIComponent`. Make sure your page has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>` in the `<head>`. And if you're using AJAX, set the request header "Content-type" as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @Ian I have tried your suggestion but it's not working.

Comment: @Infotechie Without any actual code, there's no way to help

Comment: @Ian I have added code in the question.

Comment: You didn't include the request header like I said. Add `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1");` right before the `.open()` line